# in c#, wpf, how do you set/assign value stored in database to a checkbox in datagrid based in sqlite database

Tags: c#, wpfdatagrid

In wpf, i have value in my  sqlite database column as true for one record but it is not showing up as mark checked in datagrid column.
Can someone help?
xaml code:

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="DG_VendorPur" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding VendorProducts}" Grid.Row="7" Grid.RowSpan="4" FontFamily="Franklin Gothic Medium" FontSize="18" Background="#FFEBDCEB" AlternatingRowBackground="#FFDAE7F5" SelectionMode="Single" ColumnWidth="*" Grid.Column="5" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" SelectedCellsChanged="DG_VendorPur_SelectedCellsChanged">
                    <DataGrid.Columns>
                        <DataGridCheckBoxColumn x:Name="DG_V_IsDefault" Header=" Preferred "    MinWidth="50" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=VP_isVendorActive, Mode=TwoWay}" SortDirection="Ascending" IsThreeState="True" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn     x:Name="DG_Vname"       Header=" Vendor Name "  MinWidth="50" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=VP_Vname}"       FontFamily="Calibri" />
                        <DataGridTextColumn     x:Name="DG_VItemNo"     Header=" Vendor SKU# "  MinWidth="50" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=VP_VendorSKU}"   FontFamily="Calibri"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn     x:Name="DG_VCaseCost"   Header=" Case Cost "    MinWidth="50" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=VP_SKUcaseCost}" FontFamily="Calibri"/>
                        <DataGridTextColumn     x:Name="DG_VQtyPerCase" Header=" Qty/Case "     MinWidth="50" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=VP_QtyInCase}"   FontFamily="Calibri"/>
                    </DataGrid.Columns>
                </DataGrid>
```

xaml.cs :

```
    sqliteCon.Open();
                string Product = TB_PscanID.Text;
                cmd.CommandText = "Select VP_Vname,VP_VendorSKU,VP_SKUcaseCost,VP_QtyInCase from VendorProducts where VP_ProductID= @WORD";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@word", Product);
                cmd.Prepare();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                SQLiteDataAdapter SDAdap = new SQLiteDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataTable DT = new DataTable("VendorProducts");
                SDAdap.Fill(DT);

                DG_VendorPur.ItemsSource = DT.DefaultView;
                DataRecord = DG_VendorPur.Items.Count;
                SDAdap.Update(DT);
                sqliteCon.Close();
```

Comment: How are you storing your boolean in the SQLite DB?

Comment: @axlj :true or false.

Comment: Are you using the MVVM design pattern correctly? If you're using a code-behind file then you're not. What does your ViewModel class look like?

Comment: You need to use a field type of integer and represent false/true as 0/1 respectively.

Comment: @axlj : I tried 0 or 1 too. Same thing.

Comment: @dai: i have the above code in xaml and xaml.cs

Comment: all other fields are displaying correctly.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is with your query:

```
SELECT VP_isVendorActive, /* You're missing this column */
       VP_Vname,
       VP_VendorSKU,
       VP_SKUcaseCost,
       VP_QtyInCase
FROM VendorProducts WHERE VP_ProductID= @WORD
```